# How can run multiple scenarios in citrus simulator apart from the default scenarios?

Tags: citrus-framework

I am working on citrus-simulator, I am able to run scenarios which are only default scenarios with "citrus.simulator.defaultScenario=default" property, but i want to run multiple scenarios at a time with multiple rest calls  with single simulator runner. How could i achieve this? can any one suggest.

Comment: Have you tried to create custom scenarios? Your scenarios need to map to a request message based on some identifier that is extracted from the incoming request. By default the simulator is looking for @RequestMapping annotations on your scenario for mapping incoming requests to it. Can you please provide your custom scenario code.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Actually i am working with the samples what  you were provided in citrus sample projects.Have tried with citrus-rest-simulator sample.now I am able to run scenarios with scenario names using "citrus.simulator.defaultScenario=scenario-name" property.i have a doubt .ie  how  can we write scenarios in xml dsl  in simulator is there any way?Thank you,

Comment: there is no way to write simulator scenarios in XML at the moment.

Comment: Oh k.Thanks for your response  Christoph.